# Same recommendation letter for different semesters?

Tags: recommendation-letter

I applied to a NASA internship for the spring semester, and I want to reapply for the internship for summer. Is it okay and good to ask the same professor who sent a recommendation letter for my spring application to resend the same letter for my new summer application? Does it weaken my application in any way?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that's perfectly acceptable.  I've submitted duplicate letters myself in support of reappointments for some of my students and they've all been successful.  (But like most instructors, I only agree to write an LOR if I can write a good one that I think will be helpful.)  The only reason for concern would be if you were turned down on your previous application and you worry it might have been because he/she gave you a weak reference.